# Symfony 3.0 - Cannot load resource "." - Custom Route Loader

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I am working on upgrading one of my projects to SF 3:
The project uses some custom routing loaders which where working without problems before, now I am getting a `FileLoaderLoadException` stating that the `resource "."` couldn't be loaded.

I took a look at the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html

But either nothing has changed or the documentation has not been updated.

My routing.yml configuration looks like this:

```
custom_sidebar_routing:
    resource: .
    type: sidebar
```

Can someone give me a hint what is wrong here or can confirm that this is a bug inside symfony core?

Comment: try with `resource: '.' `

Comment: thx for the idea, I already had the same one, unfortunately it's not working either (also tried *) which is not working

Comment: Hi, I see your code is equal to the doc also  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html#using-the-custom-loader

Comment: Yes, my code is exactly following the guidelines of the documentation

Comment: Does Your custom loader method looks like this?

`public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'sidebar' === $type;
    }`

Or this:


`public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'extra' === $type;
    }`

Comment: the identifier is "sidebar" but that is not the problem, symfony already crashes when trying to parse the yml file because it cannot interpret: "resource: ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem, configuration was good, but I missed to register my additional routing_loader.yml (in which I had defined my loader services) inside the BundleExtensionFile in the DependencyInjection folder