# Cannot load resource "." after writing in routing.yml

Tags: symfony

I made a command that automatically writes in routing.yml. 
My problem is that when I try to browse one of the routes

```
api:
    resource: "."
    type:     "api"
    prefix: /api
```

I get this exception

> Cannot load resource "."

I tried to add a cache:clear to my command but I get the same exception.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to automate certain configurations and routing : a command line that  write routes and bundles configurations in routing.yml and config.yml .
That works but the configurations doesn't work after being generated .

Comment: I don't remember how FOSRestBundle parses this directive but I'm afraid it is not possible the way you want. The only thing I currently see is to create another CompilerPass which will append configuration suitable you needs.

Comment: are you defining a custom loader for the type `api`?

Comment: @Matteo yes it's defined in its own bundle in the vendor

Comment: check the bundle/custom loader extension is correctly loaded, I see the same problem yesterday in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398785/symfony-3-0-cannot-load-resource-custom-route-loader#comment60414853_36398785) question

Comment: @Matteo I have a different problem. my routing is correct and loaded .
Here is my test scenario :
I execute my command api:configure
Command writes configuration in routing.yml
I browser http://localhost:8000/api/
I get the exception , I do cache:clear --> no more exception

Comment: So you need to refresh the routing cache of symfony after the creation of the new routes. I suppose this problem doesn't exist in a symfony dev environment.

Comment: I finally found a way to do it :)) thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a cache warmup that runs after the command termination that way Symfony dumps routes into generated code .

```
class TerminateListener {

    public function onConsoleTerminate(ConsoleTerminateEvent $event) {
        if ($event->getCommand()->getName() == ('my:command')) {
            $app = new Application();
            $cache_clear_command = $event->getCommand()->getApplication()->find('cache:warmup');
            $cache_clear_command->setApplication($app);
            $event->getOutput()->setVerbosity('VERBOSITY_QUIET');
            $cache_clear_command->run($event->getInput(), $event->getOutput());
        }
    }
}

services:
 warmup.listener:
        class:TerminateListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.terminate , method: onConsoleTerminate }
```